# How to create a text file with a list of specific type files using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I want to create a list of files of specific type(e.g. csv) in a directory.

To get a list of .csv files I ran below command:
Get-ChildItem D:\Test*.csv

How should I get all the csv files name and create a text file and write the names in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Test*.csv  |
    Select-Object -Expandproperty name |
    Out-File myfile.txt
```

The second command will convert the file name into a suitable format for a text file.